# В каком компоненте вызывать повторяющийся вызов на сервер, следуя Чистой архитектуре?

Tags: android, архитектура

Есть следующая задача: перед каждым 4м вызовом некоторого апи (допустим, получение страницы новостей) нужно показывать рекламный блок. Как правильно это сделать, следуя Чистой Архитектуре?

Должен ли этим заниматься репозиторий или интерактор?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это задача интерактора, так как проверка когда нужно показывать рекламу - это бизнес логика. Можно сделать у репозитория два метода: `getData` и `getAds`. А интерактор считает когда нужно показывать данные, а когда рекламу, в нём логика.